# Setting version for all Maven sub-modules in single entry in Maven Bill Of Materials(BOM)

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management, maven-bom

I have a library that has several sub modules. I have set the version for the library in the parent POM.

```
<groupId>com.softtech</groupId>
<artifactId>BatchLibrary</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Also, I have created a Maven Bill Of Materials(BOM) project where this library is defined.

**In first case**, I set the version for entire library in BOM as below

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.softtech</groupId>
            <artifactId>BatchLibrary</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**In second case**, I set the version for library's each sub module individually like below

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.softtech</groupId>
          <artifactId>BatchLibrary-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.softtech</groupId>
          <artifactId>BatchLibrary-web</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I have added this BOM to my projects. When declaring library's sub module without version in my project. In first case mentioned above, I get an error

> dependency.version is missing

In Second case, it works fine.

Is that is how BOM works? Do I have to define all the sub modules with version individually in my BOM or I can just define the parent POM of my library with version and it should work. If it should? Why It is not working in my case?

Answer (score 0):

The BOM should list the version of all the artifacts. I snipped the following from the [Importing Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies) section of the Maven website's "Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism":

> The root of the project is the BOM pom. It defines the versions of **all the artifacts that will be created in the library**. Other projects that wish to use the library should import this pom into the dependencyManagement section of their pom.